# How to rewrite code to avoid call to external dll during unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, architecture, dllimport, extern

There is class Driver, which is calling static extern method in constructor. Which is the best way to change architecture to be able to unit test Driver method.

```
public class Driver
{
    [DllImport("Driver.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateDriver();

    // Pointer to C++ Driver object
    internal IntPtr DriverPtr; // this for integration tests

    public Driver()
    {
        DriverPtr = CreateDriver();
    }

    public int SomeMethod(int a) // test only this method
    {
        return a + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you do with the `DriverPtr` within your `Driver` class? In your example you do nothing with it but creating it.

Comment: Actually it does not matter. The idea is to test SomeMethod() using unit test. Unit test cannot call dll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your story isn't entirely clear, but I think you're asking how to test the code without having to interface with the actual driver DLL. It is unclear whether you want to use the value assigned to `DriverPtr` in your constructor.

You can fix this by moving your static methods into an instance class, interfacing that class and mocking it during tests.

The interface:

```
public interface IDriverProvider
{
    IntPtr Create();
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class DriverProvider : IDriverProvider
{
    [DllImport("Driver.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateDriver();

    public IntPtr Create()
    {
        return CreateDriver();
    }
}
```

Then inject it into your using class:

```
public class Driver
{
    internal IntPtr DriverPtr;

    public Driver(IDriverProvider driverProvider)
    {
        DriverPtr = driverProvider.Create();
    }

    public int SomeMethod(int a) // test this method
    {
        return a + 1;
    }
}
```

Now you can test your class:

```
// Arrange
var driverProviderMock = new Mock<IDriverProvider>();   
var driver = new Driver(driverProviderMock.Object);

// Act
driver.SomeMethod();

// Assert
driverProviderMock.Verify(d => d.Create());
```

Comment: I just wrote the same code and i called it IDriveProvider as well. Damn it. :)

Comment: @Malmi naming things is hard, but I didn't want to spend too long on it. :P

Comment: This is exactly the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @CodeCaster Sorry, deleted my comment. Wrong person in my mind. :P You solution is great.

Comment: Would it better to use FactoryMethod pattern here?

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of ways, it depends on what you want to do.

Per example, you can create a dummy constructor with an extra param and do not do the call:

```
public Driver(bool dummy){ }
```

Or change the constructor to do noting and then have an Init() function:

```
public Driver(){ } //Can be removed, left for example clarity

public void Init(){ DriverPtr = CreateDriver(); }
```

Comment: _"can create a dummy constructor with an extra param"_ - just in order to be able to unit test it? Don't. _"and then have an Init() function"_ - and then what?

Comment: Call the Init when the class is not used for tests.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but they obviously want to access `DriverPtr` somewhere.

Comment: If he wants to use it, then the DLL must be called anyway thus the question makes no sense, look at the function example he posted, does not reference the pointer.

Comment: _"then the DLL must be called anyway"_ - no, the question very clearly is about how to test this code without actually performing the platform invoke call. It's a crappy example, but your answer doesn't really help.

Comment: completely nonsense, if the code must be test and the pointer is not initialized or initialized with a fake pointer all functions using the pointer will fail and then no testing is done, so, or the pointer can be null and my answer is correct or the user asks for an imposibility

Comment: Gusman, is it possible to call Init method from Driver constructor, however, during test, create inherited class TestDriver, where override Init method to return new IntPtr()?

Comment: If you can use an inherited class then the init method is not needed, leave your class as is and create a new class just with an empty constructor, in this way the original constructor will not be executed.